# How to programmatically build an APR1-MD5 using PHP

Tags: php, apache, md5, mod-dav-svn

Much like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916/programmaticly-building-htpasswd/) I want to generate an htpasswd file entry from PHP. However it needs to be the APR1 (Apache) style, as mentioned in the original answer (The answer did not show how to implement the APR1 style), to work with mod_dav_svn.

I can't seem to find a working implementation that will create the password.

I found this (I forget where now):

```
function crypt_apr1_md5($plainpasswd) {
    $salt = substr(str_shuffle("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"), 0, 8);
    $len = strlen($plainpasswd);
    $text = $plainpasswd.'$apr1$'.$salt;
    $bin = pack("H32", md5($plainpasswd.$salt.$plainpasswd));
    for($i = $len; $i > 0; $i -= 16) { $text .= substr($bin, 0, min(16, $i)); }
    for($i = $len; $i > 0; $i >>= 1) { $text .= ($i & 1) ? chr(0) : $plainpasswd{0}; }
    $bin = pack("H32", md5($text));
    for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
        $new = ($i & 1) ? $plainpasswd : $bin;
        if ($i % 3) $new .= $salt;
        if ($i % 7) $new .= $plainpasswd;
        $new .= ($i & 1) ? $bin : $plainpasswd;
        $bin = pack("H32", md5($new));
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $k = $i + 6;
        $j = $i + 12;
        if ($j == 16) $j = 5;
        $tmp = $bin[$i].$bin[$k].$bin[$j].$tmp;
    }
    $tmp = chr(0).chr(0).$bin[11].$tmp;
    $tmp = strtr(strrev(substr(base64_encode($tmp), 2)),
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/",
    "./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    return "$"."apr1"."$".$salt."$".$tmp;
}
```

But it doesn't generate a working password. I think this might be something to do with the version of apache but am not sure. (I am running on CENTOS 5)

Comment: This code is from the comments section of the PHP 'crypt' documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: I was getting an error where it would complain that $tmp was undefined, I simply added $tmp="" to the beginning of the funciton and it works correctly now, but I'm not sure if that is the correct way to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I made a mistake and this function does in fact create working APR1 htpasswd entries. They do look different to the ones Apache creates but they do work.

Answer (score 1):

Look for existing components that do it on sites like phpclasses.org. One example: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/5066.html.

Comment: This particular example from phpclasses doesn't even support apr1/MD5 password files, so it's useless for this particular question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you! It works like a charm.

Just a small comment: The salt can also contain "./" and "A..Z" besides "a..z0..9", so it is the same string as the 'translate-to' string in the last line. 
And sometimes you want to set the salt in addition, to create reproducable results, like:

`function crypt_apr1_md5( $plainpasswd, $salt = '' ) { 

    $translateTo = "./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

if ( $salt == '' ) { $salt = substr(str_shuffle($translateTo), 0, 8); }`

...

`$tmp = strtr(strrev(substr(base64_encode($tmp), 2)),
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/",
        $translateTo);

    return '$apr1$'.$salt.'$'.$tmp;

}`

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit hacky, but have you considered using the exec() function to call the command that generates the htpasswd ?

Comment: Yes I have, I was really trying to avoid using any system calls. In fact I am doing this to replace exactly that. It will be my last resort if I can't find another way. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

See on this:

```
1:   private function crypt_apr1_md5($plainpasswd) { </br>
7:   for($i = $len; $i > 0; $i >>= 1) { $text .= ($i & 1) ? chr(o) : $plainpasswd{0}; } </br>
16:  $tmp = ''; </br>
```