# how to generate a hash like apache's htpasswd using java

Tags: java, .htpasswd

i use "Force MD5 encryption of the password" in htpasswd to generate a hash for instance '123' i get:

use htpasswd: 123 => $apr1$kaTbKaLO$ewJXRZAKpjaxK4thy2jOp/

use MD5 digest: 123 => 202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70

please tell me how can i generate a hash like the apache htpasswd using java
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Passwords in Apache .htpasswd files are encoded using a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)). If you want to generate these passwords using Java you'll need to do the same. [This site](http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/htpasswd-generator/) has an explanation of the salt/hashing algorithm used for Apache's .htpasswd files; I am looking for an actual algorithm you could use and will edit my answer after I find one.

**EDIT**: Looks like it's been asked before, right here on SO:

[Programmaticly building htpasswd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916/programmaticly-building-htpasswd)

Here's the documentation from Apache, along with their source code:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/password_encryptions.html

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/apr/apr-util/branches/1.3.x/crypto/apr_md5.c?view=co

Answer (score 3):

I found where someone's tackled this in java & released it with a beer-ware license. Better late than never right? It's been there probably since 2007 so I'd be surprised if you hadn't eventually found it some time after asking in 2010.

> "Java Port By: Jonathan Abbey, jonabbey@arlut.utexas.edu"
>
> "MD5Crypt.java is a port of Poul-Henning Kamp's original FreeBSD
> MD5-based hash algorithm, with additional methods to support the
> Apache HTTPd server variant of this algorithm."
>
> "The resulting string will be in the form '$apr1$<salt>$<hashed mess>'"

ftp://ftp.arlut.utexas.edu/pub/java_hashes/

Answer (score 2):

Md5Crypt is what you are looking for. It implements [Apache htpasswd algorithms](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/misc/password_encryptions.html)

> Apache-specific algorithm using an iterated (**1,000 times**) MD5 digest of various combinations of a random 32-bit **salt** and the **password**.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Md5Crypt;
...
String enPasswd = Md5Crypt.md5Crypt("your plain password".getBytes());
String htpasswdContent = "your username:" + enPasswd;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_simple_class_to_compute_md5_hash.xml

Comment: yes, i used MD5 digest but the result is different with htpasswd's result

Comment: @robinmag: You need to salt and use md5 1000 times -- see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, to have

**123=>$apr1$kaTbKaLO$ewJXRZAKpjaxK4thy2jOp/**,

it is necessary to use the **apr1Crypt** method of the **Md5Crypt** class instead of the md5Crypt method of the same class.

Otherwise, instead of having 123=>$apr1$kaTbKaLO$ewJXRZAKpjaxK4thy2jOp/, we end up having 123=>$1$kaTbKaLO$ewJXRZAKpjaxK4thy2jOp/ (i.e. $1$ instead of $apr1$ before the salt as desired by the post). The code should be:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Md5Crypt;
...
String enPasswd = Md5Crypt.apr1Crypt("your plain password".getBytes());
String htpasswdContent = "your username:" + enPasswd;
```