# How to generate .htpasswd under PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htpasswd

Im trying to generate long htpasswd file with a lot of users (100+).

My DirectAdmin panel on linux server generates htpasswd file with password hashes starting with $1$.

I tried something like this:

```
function random_salt($length = 9) // 9 characters and $1$ = 12 characters
{      
    $chars = 'bcdfghjklmnprstvwxzaeiou';

    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++)
    {
        $result .= ($p%2) ? $chars[mt_rand(19, 23)] : $chars[mt_rand(0, 18)];
    }

    return $result;
}

echo crypt($myplainpassword, "$1$".random_salt());
```

It produces hash which starts with $1$, but server doesnt let me in. My passwords are 4-digit random "pin codes" generated in excel. Examples:

1215
5325
6261

What im doing wrong?

Comment: "What im doing wrong?"... using `htpasswd`

Comment: why are you using the $1$ as a part of the salt?

Comment: I agree with Petah - there probably is a better way to secure a resource rather than using htpasswd.

Comment: Also, please add more details about your setup - I am only assuming that you are using apache?

Comment: Im using $1$ as part of salt because i read somewhere that apache needs md5 salt like this.

Comment: Perhaps http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.crypt.php#73619 provides some insight.

Comment: Duplicate with : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275051/create-new-http-auth-credentials-using-php-instead-of-shell

Answer (score 1):

This how I generate the .htpasswd passwords...

```
$new_password = password_hash($old_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

> password_hash() creates a new password hash using a strong one-way
>   hashing algorithm. password_hash() is compatible with crypt().
>   Therefore, password hashes created by crypt() can be used with
>   password_hash().
>
> The following algorithms are currently supported:
>
> PASSWORD_BCRYPT - Use the CRYPT_BLOWFISH algorithm to create the hash.
>   This will produce a standard crypt() compatible hash using the "$2y$"
>   identifier. The result will always be a 60 character string, or FALSE
>   on failure. Supported Options:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into the exact way how the hashes are generated. If you create a hash using your method, does it look the same as the one generated by DirectAdmin?

In general, I have previously used [this](http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/create-password-for-htpasswd-file-using-php/) to generate the entries.

Comment: Solution from that link doesnt work. I tried this.

Hash generated from code that i pasted looks similar to that from DirectAdmin, but its not the same value. Salt is random, so i think its impossible to get same value...