# Apache basic auth, mod_authn_dbd and password salt

Tags: apache, authentication, basic-authentication

Using Apache [mod_auth_basic](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_auth_basic.html) and [mod_authn_dbd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html) you can authenticate a user by looking up that user's password in the database. I see that working if the password is held in clear, but what if we use a random string as a salt (also stored in the database) then store the hash of the concatenation?

mod_authn_dbd requires you to specify a query to select that password not to decide if the user is authenticated of not. So you cannot use that query to concatenate the user provided password with the salt then compare with the stored hash.

```
AuthDBDUserRealmQuery "SELECT password FROM authn WHERE user = %s AND realm = %s"
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Password Formats](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/password_encryptions.html) for Basic Auth it seemed that I could make this work if the hash is done using the [apr_md5_encode](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/apr/apr/trunk/crypto/apr_md5.c?view=markup) function.

Found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469197/how-to-generate-a-hash-like-apaches-htpasswd-using-java) that relates to this and links to a [Java implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469197/how-to-generate-a-hash-like-apaches-htpasswd-using-java). I used that implementation with a small change to calculate the database hash inside my website normal user-creation flow. After this i could use mod_authn_dbd with this query:

```
AuthDBDUserRealmQuery "SELECT CONCAT('$apr1$',password_salt,'$',password_hash) FROM users WHERE user = %s AND realm = %s"
```