# .htpasswd add/remove/update usernames & passwords - php windows

Tags: php, .htaccess

Can anybody tell me the simplest way (or suggest me a tutorial) to save / update / delete usernames and passwords in a `.htpasswd` file using php?? I am using php5 and Apache 2 in Windows.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916/programmaticly-building-htpasswd

Comment: not exact duplicate. look my specific title.

Comment: I don't see the distinction. The link I have provided shows you how to administer a .htpasswd file with PHP.

Answer (score 25):

I like [this](https://www.allsatis.de/blog/2012-03-22/htpasswd-dateien-anlegen-benutzer-hinzufuegen-und-loeschen):

Create file and add username:

```
htpasswd -c [filename] [username]
```

Add username into file or update users password:

```
htpasswd [filename] [username]
```

Delete user from file:

```
htpasswd -D [filename] [username]
```

Answer (score 1):

***To remove a user:***
Just open the password file using nano or vim and simply remove the user line that you want to delete...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [htpasswd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/programs/htpasswd.html) tool. I don't think it can remove the password, but save and update should be ok.

**EDIT** BTW: I'm not sure of the available operating systems.

Comment: He is on windows according to the question title. I could be wrong but I don't think htpasswd is available for Windows. Perhaps in Cygwin.