# HTTP-Authentication with .htpasswd file

Tags: php, apache, .htpasswd

PHP offers the possibility to use [HTTP-Authentication](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php).

However, it is difficult to use .htpasswd-files.

There are scripts to check the .htpasswd file within php (for example [this one](http://koivi.com/php-http-auth/)).
However, these scripts are quite complex and most of them don't support all relevant encryption types (like MD5 which is the default used by the program [htpasswd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html)).

With a standard .htaccess file it is much easier (just `AuthUserFile <.htpasswd-file>` is needed).

However, I would like to avoid an explicit .htaccess file and use php instead.

Is there an *easy* way to check a .htpasswd-file using php? Can php perhaps "ask" apache if access should be granted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that there is direct way to ask apache for authenticating user, but there are few workarounds for it:

1. implement missing algos for yourself: [APR1-MD5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php#73619), [SHA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39963/258674)
2. Use with `shell_exec("htpasswd -nb $user $password")` to generate hash and check in .htpasswd file
3. Setup virtual server on internal interface that uses .htpasswd file to authenticate and perform curl call (with user credentials) to it, checking response header (200 for authorized, 4xx for not authorized)

Comment: i see - so no really very easy way to do it... maybe (2) is a solution. thank you!

Comment: if you are going to use shell_exec, remember to double check / escape user input, before executing any command. And remember that php-only authentication will not prevent anyone from accessing static content such as images, javascripts plain html files etc.

Comment: `shell_exec("htpasswd -nbm $user $password");` worked for me!